# Foreign characters won't display in SSH

Tags: ssh, character-encoding

I'm having some problems with using `ssh` and a remote server (which I do not have admin access to) - Specifically, there are a couple of folders on there with Korean and Cyrillic text.

When I display the parent folder contents with `ls`, the characters are escaped as "?". Perhaps of note is that the Korean characters seem to escape far more ?s than the number of characters that *should* be there.

I know that the terminal program I'm using can display the characters, as using `sftp` displays them perfectly. The problem occurs across all terminals I've tried.

**Summary of machines**

Local machine:

- Linux 2.6.32-5-686, i686
- Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.2 (squeeze)
- Have admin access

Remote server:

- Linux 2.6.32-bpo.5-amd64, x86_64
- Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.8 (lenny)
- Don't have admin access, nor physical

I've probably missed some other vital statistic or bit of information, in which case I apologize. I'm fairly new to the whole non-Windows side of computing, so I barely know what I'm doing here.

Comment: post the output from the `locale` and `locale -a` commands, both locally and remotely, please

Comment: Thanks @enzotib - Your comment twigged me onto the idea that the offered locales might not be the same locally and remotely.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly/77100276

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale) information isn't set up correctly on the server machine. Specifically, the `LC_CTYPE` variable, which indicates the encoding of characters on the terminal, isn't set correctly (or, I suspect, at all).

In your local terminal, run `locale` to see your locale settings. You'll probably see (amongst other lines) something like `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`; what matters here is the `.UTF-8` part, indicating the [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. This is the de facto standard encoding for multilingual text in the unix world (and beyond).

You need to pass this information to the server. The best way, if it works, is to send locale information through the ssh connection. For this, add the following lines at the end of `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
SendEnv LC_* LANG
```

This requires that a suitable `AcceptEnv` directive be present in the server configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) (it is by default on Debian).

If that doesn't work, and you always log in to the server from a UTF-8 terminal, add the line `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` to your `~/.bashrc` on the server (or `~/.zshrc` or whatever file your shell uses). The locale name (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`) must be one of those offered by `locale -a`, and must have `.UTF-8` (or `.utf8` or some trivial variation).

Comment: Ah! That'd be the problem: I "use" en_AU.utf8 locally, which seemed to be already forwarded to the server (or, at least, the `locale` outputs matched). However, `locale -a` remotely gave only en_GB.utf8 and en_US.utf8. Thanks!

Comment: To get the encoding of the current locale, you may also use: `locale charmap`

Comment: My `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` required also sending `LANG` (`SendEnv LANG LC_*`)

Comment: And I needed to add `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` to my `~/.profile` on the server side. Adding it to `~/.bashrc` seemed to have no effect.

Comment: So, it there a way to set this on the server so that it applies by default to all users, instead of editing every `.bashrc` or `.profile`?

Comment: @SamSirry Yes, but that's usually a bad idea: not everyone has the same locale choices (whether it's a personal preference, or a constraint imposed by the software they're using).

Comment: Thanks, @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'! :) As I am building the system from scratch, I tend to be believe I'm well aware of the implications...
Anyway, for anyone looking, I found the answer here: https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/